# node-inspector debugger keep being terminated due to "listen EADDRINUSE"

Tags: node.js, macos, node-inspector

I have a node.js application that I want to debug with node-inspector on Mac OS X. I started the debugger with this command.

> **$node-debug app.js**
>
> Node Inspector is now available from
>   http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 Debugging `app.js`
>   Debugger listening on port 5858

But this node-inspector debugging process keep being terminated shortly after I try to debug/step through the code in Chrome. The error message is below:

> events.js:85
>
> ```
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
>
> at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
> at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
> at listen (net.js:1182:10)
> at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cbai/Dev/operational-insight/app.js:57:35)
> at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
> at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:501:10)
> ```

It appears to be related to port conflict as indicated by "listen EADDRINUSE". But when I list all the processes that use port 8080 and 5858 after starting the debugger, only node processes appeared.

> **$ lsof -n -i4TCP:8080 | grep LISTEN**
>
> node    72222 xxx   14u  IPv4 0x2a579a5d0db63533      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:http-alt (LISTEN)
>
> **$ lsof -n -i4TCP:5858 | grep LISTEN**
>
> node    72223 xxx   19u  IPv6 0x2a579a5cee696ef3      0t0  TCP *:5858 (LISTEN)

When the node-inspector debugger process died/error-out, port 8080 and 5858 are free and the lsof commands above return nothing. Not sure what is causing the "EADDRINUSE". I an unable to debug due to this error. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `netstat -nlp | grep 8080`?

Comment: What I do is `netstat -apn | grep 5858` to find out the PID of that process and then just do `kill -9 {PID}`. It would be great to have this handled for me automatically though.

Comment: See related [nodejs issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3469)